# Adding Content to Pre-Existing Web Page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have taken on a small web design project for a friend, and they're asking me to add something that I think is pretty simple but I can't quite figure it out. For context, I haven't managed a web page since pre-CSS days, so I know HTML pretty well, but get pretty mixed up with CSS and PHP.

As it is now, the site has two buttons in the header. They'd like me to add a third button that appears above the other two. I have found the HTML for the two existing buttons, but copy/pasting one of them did not add a third button but instead replaced the lower button with the text and link I inserted.

Here's a snippet of the PHP file:

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menu-1','container'=>'div','container_id'=>'nav','container_class'=>false,'menu_class'=>false,'menu_id'=>false )); ?>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h2>
    <h3><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></h3>
<a href="https://islandconsultingandtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/ICT-Training-Schedule-2020-2021.pdf" target="_blank" class="pdf">ICT Schedule:<br>2020/2021</a>
<a href="/docs/ICT Course Catalog 2020-2021-For Education and Social Services Professionals.pdf" target="_blank" class="pdf">ICT Catalog:<br>Educators and Social Services</a>
<a href="/docs/ICT-Course Catalog-2020-2021.pdf" target="_blank" class="pdf">ICT Catalog:<br>Law Enforcement</a>
</div>
```

As you can see I put in the third hyperlink, but I know I'm missing something, probably in the CSS, to actually put it above the other buttons.

[Site as it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7eAH.jpg)

Comment: That's not a CSS file. That seems to be your php template. If it IS your CSS file, that may be where your problems lie! There looks like there are 3 links there, so maybe there's not enough there to go on. Possibly some CSS is hiding one of the buttons?

Comment: @RichardHunter yes that is the PHP, sorry about that (will change the post). The site is made with WordPress and I'm having a helluva time finding the actual CSS file. Could be that I'm just not familiar enough with the interface.

Comment: Without seeing the CSS for the header, we have no idea what's going on and would only be guessing. Based on the code you posted, yes, you should see the three buttons. Edit: I went to the site and looked at the code, but only saw two buttons and not three.

Comment: @disinfor I had changed it back to only two buttons while I try to figure it out. The root of the issue is not being able to find this "island.css" file that is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on in that code and even more some things that some people (myself included) would consider a bad practice, namely absolutely positioning thing. I won't say it is wrong, and I definitely use it, but I try to do so sparingly.

If you add the HTML exactly as you did, you need to make the following changes to the CSS:

```css
#header .pdf {
    bottom: 0; /* was 55px */
}
#header .pdf:nth-of-type(2) {
    bottom: 100px; /* was 55px */
}
/* This block is new */
#header .pdf:nth-of-type(3) {
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

That's going to mess up responsive a bit, so you'll also have to tweak this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #header a.pdf {
        bottom: 0; /* was initial */
    }
}
```

You can change those numbers around to move things differently.

As to which file to edit, that is a little hard to say. There is either a file in the root of the WordPress install (where wp-config.php lives) called "island.css", or it lives somewhere in the "/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/" directory, but that is a little hard to tell.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. I think I can probably figure it out from here, just gotta track down that file! I feel like I'm insane because it is referenced everywhere but I can't seem to find it. I'm also picking this site up after the last designer abandoned it, so I can only claim responsibility for some of the bad practices :)

Comment: I found the file at "https://islandconsultingandtraining.com/island.css?1601925954" but I don't know how to get to in WordPress. Did I mention I hate WordPress? Lol thanks again for the help, going to keep digging!

Comment: You are going to need to go into the file system over FTP/SFTP/cPanel/etc. and manually edit that file.

Comment: Tracked down the file! Turns out there was no File Manager of any kind installed, which was throwing me off immensely. Got one installed, found the file, made the edits. It looks great on PC, but as you said, the responsiveness is all wonky, even with the edit you suggested. At this point you are a total life-saver, but any additional pointers with regards to getting that responsive back would greatly appreciated!

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks again for all of your help.